# Junit testing: Significance of fail("Not yet implemented");?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

What is the Significance of this piece of code?

e.g.

```
@Test
    public void testGetDiameter() {
        **fail("Not yet implemented");**
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Using Eclipse IDE, if you will generate JUnit TestCase stubs it will add the test methods with `fail("Not yet implemented")`. So that if you forgot to add the real implemenation the test case would fail and the error or Assertion Error will show as "Not yet implemented".

So, The eclipse stub generator give you a default implementation of your test case which will always fail and its the responsibility of Unit testcase developer to replace it with some meaningful test statements. You can think of it as `TODO:` for you.

If you remove this statement your test will PASS but in real its not doing any kind of test for you, but will simply increase the count of your testcase.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Message")
```

if you want to really keep it, but I would delete this test. For now it's doing nothing, so it's a trash.

It's better to not keep trash code.

Comment: This is useful for TDD, to signify that the method needs to be implemented.

Comment: You are right, but that should be code line with a short life.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever wrote the test intends for it to fail every time, telling whoever runs the test that there is supposed to be a test, but it has not been written yet.

Maybe your job is to replace it with an implementation which passes.